# org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, spring-security

I was trying to integrate Spring MVC application with Spring Security, but after logging in i'm getting this exception;

```
org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException
```

This is my spring-security.xml

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd">

    <http auto-config="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/" access="hasRole('USER')"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/student/**" access="hasRole('ADMIN')"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/subject/**" access="hasRole('ADMIN')"/>
        <form-login  login-page="/login"
                     username-parameter="username"
                     password-parameter="password"
                     authentication-success-handler-ref="customSuccessHandler"
                     authentication-failure-url="/accessdenied"/>
        <csrf disabled="true"/>
    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="customUserDetailsService"/>
    </authentication-manager>

    <beans:bean id="customUserDetailsService" class="com.scc.security.service.CustomUserDetailsService"/>
    <beans:bean id="customSuccessHandler" class="com.scc.security.service.CustomSuccessHandler"/>

</beans:beans>
```

This is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

    <!-- Spring MVC -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>scc</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/scc-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>scc</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Loads Spring Security config file -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-security.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

And these are the dependencies for spring security that i'm having in pom.xml;

```
<!-- Spring Security -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

For achieving role based login i'm using the following customSuccessHandler;

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy;
import org.springframework.security.web.RedirectStrategy;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class CustomSuccessHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler{

    private RedirectStrategy redirectStrategy = new DefaultRedirectStrategy();

    @Override
    protected void handle(HttpServletRequest request, 
      HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException {
        String targetUrl = determineTargetUrl(authentication);

        if (response.isCommitted()) {
            System.out.println("Can't redirect");
            return;
        }

        redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request, response, targetUrl);
    }

    protected String determineTargetUrl(Authentication authentication) {
        String url="";

        Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities =  authentication.getAuthorities();

        List<String> roles = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (GrantedAuthority a : authorities) {
            roles.add(a.getAuthority());
        }

        if (isAdmin(roles)) {
            url = "/student";
        } else {
            url="/accessDenied";
        }

        return url;
    }

    public void setRedirectStrategy(RedirectStrategy redirectStrategy) {
        this.redirectStrategy = redirectStrategy;
    }
    protected RedirectStrategy getRedirectStrategy() {
        return redirectStrategy;
    }

    private boolean isAdmin(List<String> roles) {
        if (roles.contains("ROLE_ADMIN")) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

This is my login.jsp page;

```
<c:url var="loginUrl" value="/login"></c:url>
        <form:form commandName="userForm" action="${loginUrl}" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" autocomplete="off">

                <div class="form-group">

                    <form:input path="username" id="username" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="username" autocomplete="off"/>
                    <form:errors path="username" cssStyle="color: #ff0000;"/>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">

                    <form:input path="password" id="password" class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="password" autocomplete="off"/>
                    <form:errors path="password" cssStyle="color: #ff0000;"/>
                </div>

                <a class="forgetPassword" href="#">Forgot Password ?</a>

                <div class="form-group mt-md">

                    <input class="btn btn-block btn-primary" type="submit" value="SIGN IN" name="submit">

                </div>

        </form:form>
```

But after logging in, i'm getting the following exception.

```
org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:125)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:143)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:167)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:217)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:120)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1852)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.scc.security.service.CustomUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(CustomUserDetailsService.java:30)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:114)
    ... 36 more
```

And finally this is my customUserDetailsService;

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.scc.model.RoleModel;
import com.scc.model.UserModel;
import com.scc.model.UserRoleModel;
import com.scc.security.model.SpringSecurityUser;
import com.scc.service.UserService;

@Service("customUserDetailsService")
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Transactional(readOnly=true)
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)
            throws UsernameNotFoundException {
       UserModel userModel = userService.loadUserByUsername(username);
        System.out.println("User : " + userModel);
        if( userModel == null ) {
            System.out.println("User not found");
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Username not found");
        }
        return new SpringSecurityUser(userModel.getUserId(), userModel.getUsername(), userModel.getPassword(), null, null, null, 
                getGrantedAuthorities(userModel));
    }

    private List<GrantedAuthority> getGrantedAuthorities(UserModel user) {
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();

        UserRoleModel userRoleModel = user.getUserRoleModel();
        RoleModel roleModel = userRoleModel.getRoleModel();

        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + roleModel.getRoleCode()));

        System.out.print("authorities :" + authorities);
        return authorities;
    }

}
```

To me everything look fine but obviously its not, can any one please tell me whats wrong with above codes.

Comment: `CustomUserDetailsService:30` is giving NPE, however in the code you provided `if( userModel == null ) {` is line 30, which can not produce an NPE. Please check if the exception trace and the code you provided are in for the same version. Also it's a simple 'NullPointerException`, you can probably easily debug it.

Comment: Its not even getting inside the userService.loadUserByUsername(username) method, which i'm having in the service layer.

Comment: `at com.scc.security.service.CustomUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(CustomUserDetailsService.java:30)`, this line is printed in the logs.

Comment: is this due to version mismatch or something

Answer (score -1):

hi i got same exception after run the spring boot application.
you got a do simple thing.
just check your temporary database admin table created or not. add new values to admin table like credentials. make sure test once in workbench.
then rerun the application.happy solution.